# CORS Error, when try to read CSV file in the same directory using PapaParse

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, papaparse

I am trying to read the CSV file using PapaParse but facing CORS policy error:

```
index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/macbook/Downloads/hh/csv/Patient_Experience.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

I am using following code snipped

```
var myurl='csv/Patient_Experience.csv';
Papa.parse(myurl, {
    header: true,
    download: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Also, file is present in csv directory like that **csv/Patient_Experience.csv**
I tried to put csv file in s3 and allow cors policy there but still facing same issue.

> Note: I am not using any node or any other library. Its simple plain HTML, JS flow.

Comment: Papa.parse is trying to load the file via an XMLHttpRequest, which doesn't work in a `file:///` environment. You need to use a webserver and access your page via `http://localhost...`

Comment: What if, I wanted to add these files in media player. It is working if I try to add in media player. My question is, Media player linux based players, so if it is working on media players then this should work on other environments too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with following.

1. Install http-server in your terminal.
2. Run this command again.
3. http-server your_project_directory -p 3000
4. your_project_directory, this will contain the index.html which contains script (reading from CSV using papaParse).